# Remove all events fullcalendar angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have events came from the database. Fullcalendar is working fine but how to remove all events in click button. My main goal is to reset all event when i need to. Is this possible or any other ways to achieve this goal. Im new to angular js. really appreciate your help. thanks in advance

html

```
<div class="content-panel" ng-controller="Controller">
  <div ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" class="span8 calendar" ng-model="eventSources" calendar="myCalendar"></div>
    <button type="button" ng-click="removeallevents()">Remove all Event</button>
 </div>
```

js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.calendar']);
 app.controller('Controller', function($scope, $http ,$timeout){

$scope.events = [];


$scope.myevents = function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
  $scope.loaderForm=true;
  var formdata = $scope.data;
  $http.post("EventsDate.php", formdata).then(function (response) {

        var events = [];
        var data   = response.data;

        angular.forEach(data, function(value, key){

            $scope.events.push({
                id: value.ID,
                title:  value.titleEvent,
                start:  value.dateEvent
            });

        });

      callback(events);
      $scope.loaderForm=false;

    });
  }


   $scope.removeallevents = function() {
      //function to remove all events
  }


   $scope.uiConfig = {
    calendar:{
        editable: true,
        header:{
          left: 'title',
          center: '',
          right: 'today prev,next'
        },
        dayClick: $scope.addEvent
    }
  };

    $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events,$scope.myevents];
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's posible usign full calendar function to remove events:

```
.fullCalendar('removeEvents');
```

You can find more info [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/removeEvents)

Comment: Yes i tried in my code using this angular.element('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents'); not working.
Is there any proper way to implement using angular js. Thanks im a new in angular js

Comment: where do you load the data?

Comment: everthing is working fine. all events loaded in calendar.